# distance between all typing of character in vb6.0

Tags: vb6

draw a form1 in vb6 and draw textbox1 in form1 and press f5 run this program. when i type " abc1234 " in textbox1 typing start this " abc1234 " but i show type " a b c 1 2 3 4 " in textbox1.
Its mean only some distance between all typing character.
for example
input of html 
using css

```css
letter-spacing: 1px;
```

when i type in input some distance between all typing

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want margin to be added between the characters in the `Textbox`.

This is not possible in standard control, unless you manually append and manage spaces to the text within the `Textbox`. Which will be a pain to manage (when using backspace/copy-paste/different culture/languages/etc).

Its better to look for a third-party control, or better alter your requirements.

In worst case - **Highly not-recommended** - develop your own VB6 `ActiveX Control` (some people call it `UserControl`, because of the way designer shows it).

Mind you, `TextBox/Edit` control is way more complex than custom designing other controls, since it contains text, which is extremely tricky to handle due to multiple locals/languages/windows themes/and what not.

Answer (score 0):

Well if you must add spacing to a Textbox this is how you would do it manually:

```
Dim oldString as String
Dim newString as String

oldString = "babel"

for i = 1 to len(oldString)
   newString = newString & Space(2) & Mid(oldString,i,1)
Next

msgbox newString
```

Like subdeveloper said this is not recommended but in case you must add spacing to your control this is how you would do it.